# Produce Record to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to produce a record to Kafka without passing any partition value but want to send a header and I have the below constructor methods to produce record to Kafka:

```
ProducerRecord​(java.lang.String topic, java.lang.Integer partition, java.lang.Long timestamp, K key, V value)
```

Creates a record with a specified timestamp to be sent to a specified topic and partition

```
ProducerRecord​(java.lang.String topic, java.lang.Integer partition, java.lang.Long timestamp, K key, V value, java.lang.Iterable<Header> headers)
```

Creates a record with a specified timestamp to be sent to a specified topic and partition

```
ProducerRecord​(java.lang.String topic, java.lang.Integer partition, K key, V value)
```

Creates a record to be sent to a specified topic and partition

```
ProducerRecord​(java.lang.String topic, java.lang.Integer partition, K key, V value, java.lang.Iterable<Header> headers)
```

Creates a record to be sent to a specified topic and partition

```
ProducerRecord​(java.lang.String topic, K key, V value)
```

Create a record to be sent to Kafka

```
ProducerRecord​(java.lang.String topic, V value)
```

Create a record with no key

In all the above methods, there is no way I can send a header without sending a partition value, and if I set partition as null I am getting `NullPointerException`.

Can you please advice me how to produce record in Kafka by sending a header and not partition value.

Comment: Can you share the NullPointerException stacktrace please? It should be ok to pass partiton as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka ProducerRecord Instance provides the Headers Instance where we can add key-value pairs.

You can go through the Kafka source code to get complete information.

https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java

**Example**

I tried with `kafka-clients-0.8.2.0` but this functionality is not available that version. so you need to check also Kafka's client version also.

The example given below is using `Kafka Client - 2.1.0`.

```
        ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, message);
        Headers headers = record.headers();
        headers.add(KafkaHeaders.HEADER_CLIENT_IP, Strings.bytes(Network.localHostAddress()));
        headers.add(KafkaHeaders.HEADER_CLIENT, Strings.bytes(logManager.appName));
        producer.send(record);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ProducerRecord` object has method `headers()` which returns the `Headers` interface, which in turn allows you to [`add()`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/header/Headers.html#add-java.lang.String-byte:A-) any header you like.